# Elasticsearch installation with Docker Compose and passing as userdata failing with cloud-init

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, terraform, cloud-init

I am trying to install elasticsearch on AWS instance ( Amazon Linux image) with terraform. I am using cloud-init to pass the configuration as user data. Initially i was not able to authenticate , bit got rid of the issue by passing the public-ssh key. Post the terraform build when i am doing docker ps -a i am able to see the elasticsearch containers , but i am not able to enter inside that it is throwing me error as below :-

```
"Error response from daemon: Container a77fdd60271c8bf31318be079f49e7262872cdddf26035d3f7c29048d391090b is not running".
```

I checked the cloud init output log as well, it is throwing below error:

```
Apr 25 08:03:39 cloud-init[3282]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd [254]
Apr 25 08:03:39 cloud-init[3282]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Apr 25 08:03:39 cloud-init[3282]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

Attaching the complete code
main.tf configuration.

```
resource "aws_instance" "elasticsearch_master" {
  count                = 1
  ami                  = "ami-0a669eea0befff0d2"
  instance_type        = "m5.2xlarge"
  subnet_id            = sort(data.aws_subnets.private.ids)[0]
  key_name             = "" # Not for SSH access may be used later for other AWS access.
  iam_instance_profile = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.base_profile.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    data.aws_security_group.default.id,
    aws_security_group.elasticsearch.id
  ]
  user_data            = data.cloudinit_config.elasticsearch_master.rendered
  user_data_replace_on_change = true 
  tags = {
    Name = "elasticsearch-master${var._env}-${count.index}"
  }
  ## Adding Volume 
  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = 950
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true
    kms_key_id            = data.aws_kms_key.default.arn
  }

}


data "cloudinit_config" "elasticsearch_master" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = file("${path.root}/elastic_docker_image/elasticsearch_master.sh")
  }

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = file("${path.root}/elastic_docker_image/elastic_pub.yml")
  }
}
```

Docker Docker compose and elastic-search installation (wrote the bash script and passed as above)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Install Docker
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install docker -y
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user


# Install Docker Compose
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-compose > /dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose version

# Create Elasticsearch Docker Compose file
cat << EOF > docker-compose.yml
version: '2.2'
services:
  es_service_1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0-arm64
    container_name: es_container_1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=pds-dev
      - node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xms4g"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./es_data_1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200" 
    networks:
      - elastic_network

  es_service_2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0-arm64
    container_name: es_container_2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=pds-dev
      - node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xms4g"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_container_1
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./es_data_2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic_network

  es_service_3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0-arm64
    container_name: es_container_3
    environment:
      - cluster.name=pds-dev
      - node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xms4g"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_container_1
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./es_data_3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic_network

networks:
  elastic_network:
    driver: bridge

EOF

# Start Elasticsearch Docker Compose
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

I tried installing elasticsearch with above steps , but i am not able to install it on AWS ec-2 instance . The container is not coming up and i am not get indie the container.

Comment: I would probably start with reading the logs for the containers if possible.

Comment: @MarkoE i am getting  xec /bin/tini: exec format error while checking docker logs, i used this command docker logs <container id>

Comment: And does the `docker-compose.yml` you create actually work if you run it locally or it has the same problem?

Comment: @MarkoE  i tried it just now locally it has the same problem

Comment: So I would suggest then fixing the issue locally since it can be harder to do it in a cloud environment. And maybe run without `-d` so you can get the logs in the terminal immediately, i.e., run just `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @MarkoE i ran the command get below result : docker-compose up
Starting es_container_7 ... done
Starting es_container_6 ... done
Starting es_container_8 ... done
Attaching to es_container_7, es_container_8, es_container_6
es_container_7  | exec /bin/tini: exec format error
es_container_8  | exec /bin/tini: exec format error
es_container_6  | exec /bin/tini: exec format error
es_container_7 exited with code 1
es_container_8 exited with code 1
es_container_6 exited with code 1

Comment: @HarshVardhan from your last comment, it looks there is issue with `Tini` binary file format. Try to build tini binary from your system source and run `docker-compose up` again

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov I tried this approach and it worked out .. thank you !

Comment: @HarshVardhan Good to hear, post your answer as a solution and close the question